# Can Javascript "access" divs from Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a main programme that has a couple of Javascript routines, one of which is Ajax. The Ajax call returns html with divs with id's and I would like the other Javascript routine in the calling page to modify the attributes of the returned html. Is this possible? I've run some tests and I can't get it to work.

### **Update**

This is in the head

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Ajax()
        {
            var
                $http,
                $self = arguments.callee;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                } catch(e) {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
            }

            if ($http) {
                $http.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                        setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
                    }
                };
                $http.open('GET', 'random7.php' + '?minutes=' + new Date().getMinutes() + '&seconds=' + new Date().getSeconds(), true);
                $http.send(null);
            }

        }


var galleryId = 'gallery'; /* change this to the ID of the gallery list */
var    gallery; /* this will be the object reference to the list later on */
var galleryImages; /* array that will hold all child elements of the list */
var currentImage; /* keeps track of which image should currently be showing */
var previousImage;
var preInitTimer;
preInit();

/* functions */

function preInit() {
/* an inspired kludge that - in most cases - manages to initially hide the image    gallery list
   before even onload is triggered (at which point it's normally too late, and the whole list already
   appeared to the user before being remolded) */
if ((document.getElementById)&&(gallery=document.getElementById(galleryId))) {
    gallery.style.visibility = "hidden";
    if (typeof preInitTimer != 'undefined') clearTimeout(preInitTimer); /* thanks to Steve Clay http://mrclay.org/ for this small Opera fix */
} else {
    preInitTimer = setTimeout("preInit()",2);
}
}

function fader(imageNumber,opacity) {
/* helper function to deal specifically with images and the cross-browser differences in opacity handling */
    var obj=galleryImages[imageNumber];
    if (obj.style) {
    if (obj.style.MozOpacity!=null) { 
        /* Mozilla's pre-CSS3 proprietary rule */
        obj.style.MozOpacity = (opacity/100) - .001;
    } else if (obj.style.opacity!=null) {
        /* CSS3 compatible */
        obj.style.opacity = (opacity/100) - .001;
    } else if (obj.style.filter!=null) {
        /* IE's proprietary filter */
        obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+opacity+")";
    }
   }
}

function fadeInit() {
if (document.getElementById) {
    preInit(); /* shouldn't be necessary, but IE can sometimes get ahead of itself and trigger fadeInit first */
    galleryImages = new Array;
    var node = gallery.firstChild;
    /* instead of using childNodes (which also gets empty nodes and messes up the script later)
    we do it the old-fashioned way and loop through the first child and its siblings */
    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType==1) {
            galleryImages.push(node);
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    for(i=0;i<galleryImages.length;i++) {
        /* loop through all these child nodes and set up their styles */
        galleryImages[i].style.position='absolute';
        galleryImages[i].style.top=0;
        galleryImages[i].style.zIndex=0;
        /* set their opacity to transparent */
        fader(i,0);
    }
    /* make the list visible again */
    gallery.style.visibility = 'visible';
    /* initialise a few parameters to get the cycle going */
    currentImage=0;
    previousImage=galleryImages.length-1;
    opacity=100;
    fader(currentImage,100);
    /* start the whole crossfade process after a second's pause */
    window.setTimeout("crossfade(100)", 1000);
   }
}

function crossfade(opacity) {
    if (opacity < 100) {
        /* current image not faded up fully yet...so increase its opacity */
        fader(currentImage,opacity);
        /* fader(previousImage,100-opacity); */
        opacity += 10;
        window.setTimeout("crossfade("+opacity+")", 30);
    } else {
        /* make the previous image - which is now covered by the current one fully - transparent */
        fader(previousImage,0);
        /* current image is now previous image, as we advance in the list of images */
        previousImage=currentImage;
        currentImage+=1;
        if (currentImage>=galleryImages.length) {
            /* start over from first image if we cycled through all images in the list */
            currentImage=0;
        }
        /* make sure the current image is on top of the previous one */
        galleryImages[previousImage].style.zIndex = 0;
        galleryImages[currentImage].style.zIndex = 100;
        /* and start the crossfade after a second's pause */
        opacity=0;
        window.setTimeout("crossfade("+opacity+")", 6000);
    }

}

/* initialise fader by hiding image object first */
addEvent(window,'load',fadeInit)

/* 3rd party helper functions */

/* addEvent handler for IE and other browsers */
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture)
{
 if (elm.addEventListener){
 elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
 return true;
} else if (elm.attachEvent){
 var r = elm.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn);
 return r;
}
}

    </script>
```

The Ajax call is like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">;
    setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 10000);
    </script>;
    <div id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>;
```

The Ajax php page returns code like this:

```
echo "<ul id=\"gallery\" style=\"height:325;\">";
echo "<li><img src=\"Image1.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></li>";
echo "<li><img src=\"Image2.jpeg\" alt=\"\" /></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

I know that the fader code works in a standalone fashion because I've used it many times but it won't work in conjunction with Ajax.

Comment: Yes it is. Can you show us your code, so we can see where you're stuck and help you out?

Comment: OK, but it is horribly complicated; it uses a third party piece of software to modify the opacity of images in the returned code.

Comment: Please only show the relevant parts, that are enough for us to understand/reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why did you do that? Is your code the answer to your question? I guess not. Also please format your code (proper indentation) so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to know if it is possible to make an Ajax request that returns html. When the Ajax call returns you want to manipulate the html, and then presumably display it.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html :'<div id="cat">My name is <span class="name">Alice</span></div>'
    },
    type: 'post'
}).always(function(data){
    var element = $(data);
    var name = element.find('.name');
    name.text('Bob');
    element.appendTo(document.body);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cs6tmz6k/

Answer (score 0):

***Problem #1***

When you receive the HTML in the `Ajax()` function, you replace your current gallery with it, hoping that the `crossfade()` function won't see anything. Unfortunatly, your new images are not in the `galleryImages` variable, so the `crossfade()` function won't take care of them.

You need to do another `fadeInit()` to get all these guys sorted out.

In your Ajax function, add that call:

```
document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
fadeInit();    /* register the new elements */
```

***Problem #2***

Now, the slideshow keeps rolling, but it's accelerating! That's because every time you do an update, the `crossfade()` function is still looping for all of the previous picture sets. To be able to stop it and restart fresh, store the timeout in a variable, which we can clear when needed.

```
/* At the top of your JS code */
var crossTimer;

/* In your crossfade() function */
crossTimer = window.setTimeout("crossfade("+opacity+")", 30);
```

Now, just clear it in your Ajax function

```
document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
if (typeof crossTimer != 'undefined') clearTimeout(crossTimer);
fadeInit();
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Thank you (sorry I didn't reply sooner, I was in bed!)
It's loading the images and manipulating the opacity but it does seem to have an acceleration problem.